# Does PHP `Imagick::writeImageFile` support two arguments and if not how to stipulate format?

Tags: php, imagick

The [official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimagefile) is a little imprecise whether `Imagick::writeImageFile` only supports a single file stream as parameter or also supports an additional second parameter to stipulate the image format.

If the second parameter is indeed not (officially) supported how do I stipulate the image format to use? Note, that streams opposed to file names have no intrinsic file extension. For example, in my specific use case most streams are memory buffers obtained by `fopen('php://memory')`.

Comment: I believe incoming images will be recognized my their header bytes, output image format will be determined when saved to file based on their filename extension. According to the source, you can specify the format as just an extension. e.g. 'png' https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/blob/b787cb908eec4ace911544df0e55f8bb4e7f0934/tests/022-writeimagefileformat.phpt#L50